# Mavericks XAMPP install PHP GD2 extension

Tags: php, xampp, osx-mavericks, gd2

I am using XAMPP for my PHP development on Mavericks. I am using PHPExcel for excel manipulations. The problem is PHPExcel requires PHP GD2 extension.

Please guide me how to install this extension on my MAC OSX.

Comment: waiting for its answer

Answer (score 0):

This link should help you out. https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=136656